# Lookup column, using one or two features?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column, feature, feature-activation

I have 2 lists with a lookup column. I'm thinking about 2 choices. Even putting them in the same feature or separate them in 2 features.

My question is : Does putting the lists in the same feature in order guarantee that they will be deployed in the same order ?

Answer (score 2):

Keeping them in the same feature will also work, just make sure the Parent list is up in the hierarchy of feature items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you're telling me that putting them in the order guarantee that they will be installed in the same order. Could you please provide me with a microsoft link that explains that, it will be a proof when arguing :). Thanks

Comment: hmm.. well I have tried that personally don't know if it's explained in any documentation.. But a quick test will surely clear all the confusions.. try it in a test environment..

Comment: Thanks @Arsalan, I've tried that in my test environment and it didn't work. I linked the lookup field to the "Title" column, but I find that it's linked to the "ID" and you can't even choose an ID. I had to update the lookup field to make it work, it's like it needed an internal refresh to find the other list.

Comment: hmm.. how are you creating the lists, if declarative can you share your Elements.xml file?